# Racket - how to change property value of an struct

Tags: racket

I have the following struct:

```
(define-struct my-struct (label value))
```

I want to change the property value of all items in my list. I want to set the value 2 in all items.

```
(define (change-value mylist priority)
  ( cond
    [( empty? mylist) mylist] 
    [else ( cons ((struct-copy my-struct (first mylist) [value 2]) ) (change-value (rest mylist) value) )]))
)
```

I am trying to use `struct-copy` but I am getting the following error:

`struct-copy: this function is not defined`

Any idea why I am getting this error? Should I import any library?

Comment: What language are you using? `struct-copy` should be available in normal Racket, so are you using something else like Beginning Student Language, Intermediate Student Language, or another more restrictive language?

Comment: Ok, yes I am using the Student Language. Is such function not contained in this version?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you intended your code to do. Here's a version that traverses the list of "my-struct" and sets all the "value" properties to 2:

```
#lang racket

(define-struct my-struct (label value) #:transparent)

(define (change-value mylist)
  (for/fold ([result '()])
            ([s (in-list mylist)])
    (cons (struct-copy my-struct s [value 2]) result)))
```

If I run it I get:

```
> (define l (list (my-struct 1 3) (my-struct 4 6) (my-struct 8 7)))
> l
(list (my-struct 1 3) (my-struct 4 6) (my-struct 8 7))
>
> (change-value l)
(list (my-struct 8 2) (my-struct 4 2) (my-struct 1 2))
```

Comment: At the end I am generating a new struct via make-my-struct. With struct-copy I am getting an error. The command struct-copy is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

You can change struct by build another struct e.g. if we want to switch element inside struct.

```
#lang racket

(define-struct s (s1 s2) #:transparent #:mutable)

(define (switch st)
  (s (s-s2 st) (s-s1 st)))

;;; TEST

(switch (s 1 2)) ; (s 2 1)
```

So in here we can use `map` change every second element inside struct.

```
#lang racket

(define-struct my-struct (label value) #:transparent #:mutable)

(define (change-value->2 lst-of-struct new-value)
  (map (λ (s) (my-struct (my-struct-label s) new-value))
       lst-of-struct))

;;; TEST
(change-value->2 (list (my-struct 'a 1) (my-struct 'b 1) (my-struct 'c 1))
                 2)
```